# Verifying proof that $f$ has an inflection point at zero if $f$ is a function that satisfies a given set of hypotheses.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives, proof-verification

> Prove that if $f$ is a function $f(x): f'(x) > 0$ $\forall x: x \neq 0
>  \wedge f'(0) = 0 \wedge f''$ is a continuous one to one function on
>    some open interval $(a, b): a < 0 < b$ then $f$ must have an
>    inflection point at zero.

Set $f$ to be some function $f(x): f'(x) > 0$ $\forall x: x \neq 0 \wedge f'(0) = 0 \wedge f''$ is a continuous one to one function on some open interval $(a, b): a < 0 < b$.

Assume that $f''(0) > 0$. Now since $f''$ is given to be continuous, $f'' > 0$ at values of $x: x \to 0$.

This implies $f'$ is strictly increasing near $0$, but $f'(0) = 0$. Thus $f' < 0$ to left of $0$ and $f' > 0$ to the right when $f'$ is near $0$, which contradicts the definition of $f'$.

The argument and conclusion is similar assuming $f''(0) < 0$, which again leads to a contradiction. Thus, $f''(0) = 0$. Since $f''$ is given to be continuous and 1$\to$1 along its interval, $f''$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing along its interval, which implies that $f''$ changes sign at $0$, and thus $x = 0$ is an inflection point.

Comment: Your argument is correct. What is not so correct, and makes your question difficult to understand, is the presentation of the hypotheses for $f$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Could you make some suggestions that would improve its presentation? Thanks.

Comment: Let $f$ be defined on some interval $(a,b)$ containing $0$, and assume that $f$ satisfies the following: $f$ is $C^2$, $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\ne0$, $f'(0)=0$, and $f''$ is injective. – In particular the sequence of symbols $f(x):f'(x)>0\forall x:x\ne0>\wedge f'(0)=0$ is disturbing.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Does that not read as "define $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)$ is greater than $0$ for all $x$ not equal to $0$ and $f'(0)$ is equal to 0"? That seems like a pretty simple statement.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Someone edited my hypotheses and added a greater than after $x \neq 0$ for some reason. I really don't like when people edit my questions, for reasons like this.

Comment: What Christian means (I think) and which I agree with is that you should try to use more words instead of all the symbols. It makes it so much more readable. There is no rule that says that the more abstract it's written the better mathematics it is.

Comment: @Winther Fair enough.